# Probabilistic ifelse statement in JAGS

Tags: if-statement, bayesian, jags

I want a variable inside a JAGS model to be assigned a value with probability p[i] and another value with probability 1-p[i]. p[i] is a variable in the model.

I have tried the following but I am not sure it is appropriate. I am afraid a single value (0 or 1) will be attributed to subject i and this value will always stay the same: for a given subject i, the values in the vector a[i] will always be equal to 20 or to 30. What I would like to get instead is a vector containing 20s and 30s, with the probability of 20 being equal to p[i].

```
  for (i in 1:n) {
  m[i] ~ dbin(p[i],1) 
  a[i] <- ifelse(m[i]==1, 20, 30)     
  }
```

Comment: BUGS language -- which is what JAGS reads -- is a model declarative language that was inspired on R and was meant to look and feel like R, instead of being actually a subset of R language, which is a procedural language.  So the R function `ifelse` is not part of BUGS language.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like.

```
for(i in 1:n){
m[i] ~ dbern(p[i])
a[i] <- (m[i] * 20) + ((1 - m[i]) * 30)
}
```

When the Bernoulli trail takes a 1 at probability `p`, `a` becomes 20. When it takes a 0 it becomes 30.